# Connection from unknown AWS IP to Meilisearch daemon Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu

Here's some information: I have a working project on Laravel, that uses Meilisearch as a search engine on Ubuntu 18.04. Meilisearch launched as a pm2 fork, port 7700 is not exposed. All incoming requests for searching to Meilisearch are being proxied by Laravel.

`netstat -tnpa` output:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7700          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1802/meilisearch    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      - 
tcp       32      0 172.31.22.27:57534      35.167.210.48:443       CLOSE_WAIT  1802/meilisearch
...
```

Last row is the connection from AWS IP.
What it can be? Is this something to worry about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from it's README.md, it's Meilisearch [telemetry](https://github.com/meilisearch/MeiliSearch#telemetry)

> MeiliSearch collects anonymous data regarding general usage. This helps us better understand developers' usage of MeiliSearch features.
>
> ...
>
> This program is optional, you can disable these analytics by using the `MEILI_NO_ANALYTICS` env variable.

Meilisearch's [telemetry](https://github.com/meilisearch/MeiliSearch/blob/v0.19.0/meilisearch-http/src/analytics.rs#L129) itself is powered by [Amplitude](https://amplitude.com/):

```rust
let response = ureq::post("https://api.amplitude.com/httpapi").send_string(&body);
```

Try running `dig` in your server and match its IP addresses with your `netstat` result. Something like

```sh
dig +noall +answer api.amplitude.com
```

should suffice.